# Bash, Always display colored bar at top of screen

Tags: bash

Is there anyway to modify the bash profile scripts to always display a colored bar at top of screen.  I have a requirement to show a colored hostname, username, and ipaddress on the screen at all times, but i don't want to overload PS1 as it would make the prompt take up over half of the default console width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not perfect, but this shows you how to fix part of your prompt on the first row of the screen:

```
PS1='\w \[\e[s\e[1;1H\e[42m\]\h \u ipaddress\[\e[0m\e[u\]\$ '
```

A breakdown:

- `\e[s` - save the current cursor position
- `\e[1;1H` - move the cursor to row 1, column 1 (numbered from the upper left-hand corner
- `\e[u` - restore the cursor to the previously saved position
- `\e42m` - make the background green
- `\e0m` - restore the default foreground/background colors
- `\[...\]` - enclose the various non-printing characters so that `bash` can correctly compute the length of the prompt.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) lists other escape codes. The two things missing from this answer are how to extend the bar all the way across the string and how to set the correct IP address.

Update: I believe this covers the changes that ruckc made:

```
PS1='\[\e[s\e[1;1H\e[42m\e[K\h \u ipaddress\e[0m\e[u\]\w \$ '
```

Comment: Nice. Some fixes: `'\[\e[r\e[1H\e[1;42m\eK\h \u whatever\e[u\e[0m\]\w\$ '`. `\e[K` clears the line (to the selected background colour). Also, the entire text pasted onto line one shouldn't be counted in the length of the prompt, so it's all inside `\[ \]`. And I put the entire text to be shown as the prompt at the end, instead of splitting it. (oh, and I made the top line bold)

Comment: However, there are various problems: 1) it destroys scrollback. 2) It doesn't work with curses applications like `man` and `top`

Comment: There is the so-called alternate terminal, which full-screen programs like `less` (the formatter for `man`) `top`, and curses-based programs, can use to display their output. The prompt does not appear on the alternate terminal (which may also be a problem for you). When the program ends, you return to the regular terminal, where the full prompt is still displayed. I forget the details of how you enable/disable the alternate terminal, but I think it is emulator-specific. The alternate terminal also destroys scrollback, so I've learned to live without it :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot: from the net-tools package, http://net-tools.berlios.de/, `hostname -I` will show the ip address(es). It's probably installed if you use debian/ubuntu, at least.

Answer (score 3):

How about add a \n inside your PS1, so that you always use a new line with full width?

Comment: My recommendation too: `PS1="\u@\h:\w\n\$ "`

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for something less hacky (but maybe overkill), consider byobu

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_(software)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are using xterms, you could set the xterm title instead:

```
export PS1="\[\033]0;\u $(host $(hostname))\007\]\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

This sets your xterm title, and sets your prompt to contain username@host:pwd.

My .bashrc contains something like this so PS1 is set correctly depending on whether we're in an xterm or not:

```
if [[ -n "$TERM" ]] ; then
    if ( echo $TERM | $GREP -q xterm ) ; then
        export PS1="\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]\u@\h:\w\$ "
    else
        export PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ "
    fi
fi
```